# Error: -copyFromLocal: java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: hadoop

I am new at Java, Hadoop etc.
I am having a problem when trying to copy a file to HDFS.
It says: "-copyFromLocal: java.net.UnknownHostException: quickstart.cloudera (...)"

How can I solve this? It is a exercise. You can see the problem in the imagem below.

[Image with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmSO8.png)

[Image 2 with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V0Rl.png)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error says you need to supply the HDFS folder path as destination. So the code should be like:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal words.txt /HDFS/Folder/Path
```

Almost all errors that you get while working in Hadoop are Java errors as MapReduce was mostly written in Java. But that doesnt mean there is some Java error in it.

Comment: Hi @abhiieor, thank you for your answer. I tried the code but still says the same error. Is there any other option? Thanks!

Comment: You can see "Image 2 with the erro" in the question. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't mean literal `/HDFS/Folder/Path` but rather actual HDFS folder. If you don't have any then run `hadoop fs -mkdir /user/Gus/words` to create a new folder.